# How does a function parameter pack look like?

Tags: c++11

Per the most recent c++ lang spec, there are three types of parameter pack : template parameter pack, function parameter pack, and init-capture pack. In the following code

```
template<typename ...T> 
void fun(T...t) 
{
};
```

Which one is the function parameter pack : T in "typename ...T", or, T or t in "T...t" ?
Many thanks!!!

Comment: I guess if "typename ...T" is used with a function declaration, T in which is called "function parameter pack", and "T...t" is a pack expansion. If "typename ...T" is used with a class declaration, T is called "template parameter pack", is this right ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack